# Python - Selenium - Problema con código en loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

soy nuevo en esto de selenium así que perdónenme si el código es muy básico pero es lo que he hecho hasta ahora ya que aun sigo aprendiendo. El problema que tengo con el codigo es que termina inesperadamente cada vez que se ejecuta de acuerdo a lo siguiente:

```
Message: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found
(Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 79, in <module>
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
value = method(self._driver)
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 189, in __call__
elements = _find_elements(driver, self.locator)
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 422, in _find_elements
raise e
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 420, in _find_elements
return driver.find_elements(*by)
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
'value': value})['value'] or []
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\lucebal\Anaconda3\envs\py36_knime\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 
uniqueContextId not found
(Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
```

El código al cual hace referencia es el siguiente (por motivos de privacidad las urls no las puedo indicar, pero el error no figura estar asociado a el).

```
    from asyncio import wait_for
    from datetime import datetime
    from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
    import time
    import webbrowser
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from datetime import datetime
    #INICIALIZACION DEL DRIVER
    PATH=(r"C:\Users\lucebal\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(URL1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(200)
    #INGRESO A LA WEB
    Frame1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(Frame1)
    rut=driver.find_element(By.ID,"vCARACTER")
    rut.send_keys(RUT)
    password=driver.find_element(By.ID,"vPASSWORD")
    password.click()
    password.send_keys(PASSWORD)    
    button_login=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL2)
    button_login.click()
    modulo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL3)
    modulo.click()
    endosos = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL4)
    endosos.click()
    mod_endoso = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL5)
    mod_endoso.click()
    informe_prima=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL6)
    informe_prima.click()
    Frame2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,URL6)
    driver.switch_to.frame(Frame2)
    driver.implicitly_wait(7200)
    # TABLA PARA LEER TEMPORAL
    tabla_rebaja = input_table_1.copy()
    #CONTEO DE FILAS PARA EL LOOP
    n_filas = len(tabla_rebaja['CARTA'])
    #LOOP PARA LA AUTOMATIZACION DE CARTAS 1-1
    for i in range(n_filas):
        CANAL = tabla_rebaja['CANAL'][i]
        SOLICITANTE = tabla_rebaja['RESPONSABLE'][i]
        MOTIVO = tabla_rebaja['MOTIVO DEVOLUCIÓN'][i]
        CARTA = tabla_rebaja['CARTA'][i]
        NCHEQUE = tabla_rebaja['CARTA_1'][i]
        #ESPERAR A QUE CARGUEN LOS SELECT
        WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,URL7)))    
        WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/select")))
        WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select")))
        WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/select")))
        #SELECCION DE CANAL EN MENU DESPLEGABLE
        canal_entidad =         Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select"))
        canal_entidad.select_by_index(0)
        canal_entidad.select_by_value(CANAL)
        #SELECCION DE RUT EN MENU DESPLEGABLE   
        rut_entidad =         Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/select"))
        rut_entidad.select_by_visible_text(SOLICITANTE)
        #SELECCION DE MOTIVO EN MENU DESPLEGABLE
        motivo_entidad =         Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select"))
        motivo_entidad.select_by_visible_text(MOTIVO)
        #SELECCION DE CARTA EN MENU DESPLEGABLE
        carta_entidad = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/select"))
        carta_entidad.select_by_visible_text(CARTA)
        #CHEQUEO DE CONSISTENCIA DE INFORMACION
        canal_entidad = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select").click()
        canal_seleccionado = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select").get_attribute("data-gxoldvalue")
        carta_seleccionada = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/select").get_attribute("data-gxoldvalue")
        print(CANAL, CARTA, canal_seleccionado,carta_seleccionada)
        if CANAL == canal_seleccionado and CARTA == carta_seleccionada:
            genera_cheque_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span/span/span/span/input")
            genera_cheque_button.click()
            WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select")))
            WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")))
            WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/input")))
            seleccion_aseguradora = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select"))
            seleccion_aseguradora.select_by_value("76620816")
            n_de_cheque = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
            n_de_cheque.click()
            n_de_cheque.send_keys(NCHEQUE)
            fecha_de_corte = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/div/input")
            now = datetime.now()
            date_time = now.strftime("%d") + "/" + now.strftime("%m") + "/" + now.strftime("%Y")
            fecha_de_corte.clear()
            fecha_de_corte.click()
            fecha_de_corte.send_keys(date_time)
            volver_atras_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")
            volver_atras_button.click()
            tabla_rebaja['ACCIÓN'][i] = "CARTA REBAJADA"
            print("CARTA REBAJADA")
        else:
            print("CARTA NO REBAJADA")
    driver.close()
    output_table_1 = tabla_rebaja
```

La linea a la cual hace referencia el error es la 79, la cual es la siguiente:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver,7200).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select")))
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar a entender cual es el origen del problema y así poder aprender que estoy haciendo mal. También acepto criticas y mejoras al código por supuesto.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando intente ussar selenium fue un dolor de cabeza, la mayoria de las veces fallaba porque la pagina demoraba mucho en cargar o no lograban identificar el elemento de condicion en cierta cantidad de tiempo, ese metodo WebDriverWait arrojara error si cierta cantidad de tiempo se cumple sin encontrar la condicion.

Comment: Así es Marcelo, por eso le coloco un tiempo de espera mas o menos grande para que no tenga problemas en encontrar los elementos cuando carga la pagina, es mas yo pensaba que con el implicit wait era suficiente, quizás si sea suficiente.

Comment: realmente no se como funciona el algoritmo de busqueda de elementos web de selenium pero a mi solo me funciono  despues de mucha falla del metodo usando el id pero entrando paso a paso a los contenedores de elementos de otra forma no me funcionaba